# UICollectionView performBatchUpdates inserting, deleting, and moving at the same time

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to use the `UICollectionView`'s `performBatchUpdates` method to perform a filtering operation (sorta), and inside the block I'm inserting cells, moving cells, and deleting cells.  I'm getting some weird results, so I'm wondering if this behavior is actually supported (I'm figuring the indicies are getting all messed up).  Do I just need to break each "type" of action (insert, move, and delete) into separate, distinct blocks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All operations inside `performBatchUpdates` are performed against the current indices. So no, you shouldn't have to break up insertions/deletions/movements into different blocks, that's exactly what `performBatchUpdates` is for. Without some code or a description of the weirdness you're seeing it's hard to help...

Comment: It actually turned out to be a bug elsewhere in my code.  I was concerned about indicies being screwed up from compound actions, where inside the call to `performBatchUpdates` I delete at index 0, and then insert at 0, etc...  it does seem to be working correctly now.  Thanks, just wanted to confirm I could batch operations of different types.

Comment: Actually the indices used depend on the operation - from documentation - "Deletes are processed before inserts in batch operations. This means the indexes for the deletions are processed relative to the indexes of the collection view’s state before the batch operation, and the indexes for the insertions are processed relative to the indexes of the state after all the deletions in the batch operation."

Comment: Just wanted to jump in here and agree that the accepted answer here is wrong! @safety is correct that you must update your insert indexes when deleting in the same block.

Comment: Indeed, it's the wrong answer. Check docs: inserts are based on post-deletion indices https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618042-movesection

Answer (score 1):

Just found this answer looking for an ordering for various operations and thought I would share what I have discovered regarding section insertion/deletion when coupled with item insertion deletion (no moving). I was working on filtering a `UICollectionView` and deleting cells/sections when things became empty and repopulating them when clearing the search. I was backing it with essentially an array of arrays.

I found I needed to compute the deleted items with rows and section indices from before removing the sections I wanted to delete from the datasource. (pre-section delete)

Then delete the sections from the datasource and store of those indexes for deletion.

Then insert any new sections/ sorting if needed/ and keep track of all those inserted sections.

Finally calculate the inserted rows based off the new section indexes.

```
Deleted Sections: (pre deleted index)
Inserted Sections: (indexes after deleting the deleted sections and adding these back in)
Deleted Rows: (row, pre-deleted section)
Inserted rows: (row, section based on index after inserting new sections)
```

this was with iOS 9.