# How to order moves, inserts, deletes, and updates in a UICollectionView performBatchUpdates block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

In my `UICollectionView`, I use a simple array of custom objects to produce and display cells. Occasionally that data changes and I'd like to animate the changes all at once. I've chosen to do this by tracking all the changes in a second array, diff'ing the two, and producing a set of move, insert, delete, and update operations inside of a `performBatchUpdates` block. I now realize it's pretty tricky to do all of these inside the same block because you have to worry about orders of operations with indexes. In fact, the accepted answer to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751255/uicollectionview-performbatchupdates-inserting-deleting-and-moving-at-the-same) is wrong (but corrected in the comments).

The documentation seems pretty lacking, but it covers one case:

> Deletes are processed before inserts in batch operations. This means
>   the indexes for the deletions are processed relative to the indexes of
>   the collection view’s state before the batch operation, and the
>   indexes for the insertions are processed relative to the indexes of
>   the state after all the deletions in the batch operation.

However, the document doesn't talk about when moves are processed. If I call `moveItemAtIndexPath` and `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` in the same `performBatchUpdates`, should the move indexes be relative to the pre- or post-deleted order? How about `insertItemsAtIndexPaths`?

Finally, I'm facing issues calling `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` and `moveItemAtIndexPath` in the same operation:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException attempt to delete
>   and reload the same index path

Is there a way to do all the operations I want in the same `performBatchUpdates`? If so, what order do the updates get processed relative to the others? If not, what do people usually do? Reload the data after doing all other operations? Before? I'd much prefer if all the animations happened in a single stage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the move operations, the from indexPath is pre-delete indices, and the to indexPath is post-delete indices. Reloads should only be specified for indexPaths that have not been inserted, deleted, or moved. This is probably why you're seeing the `NSInternalInconsistencyException`.

A handy way to verify the operations are set up correctly: the set of reload, insert and move-to indexPaths should not have any duplicates, and the set of reload, delete, and move-from indexPaths should not have any duplicates.

UPDATE:

It appears that items that you move are not also updated, but only moved. So, if you need to update and move an item, you can perform the reload before or after the batch update (depending on the state of your data source).

Comment: So let's say I have a cell that needs updating because it'll be displayed different (different color, for example), and I also need to move it. This is an example of where I need to move and reload. Is there any way to do these in the same animation block?

Comment: Because you're doing the move, the cell will automatically reload. You don't need to explicitly reload it.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize (and I guess I failed to experiment this case). I assumed it would just move the content containers without reloading them.

Comment: Cool. Make sure to accept the answer if it fixed your problem. :)

Comment: Are moves before or after inserts? Or is a move the same as a delete plus an insert in terms of indexing?

Comment: The latter. To figure out your move indexes, pretend it’s a delete and an insert.

Answer (score 22):

[Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38625897/404321) is right. I'd recommend watching [WWDC's 2018 Session 225 "A Tour of UICollectionView"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/225/) to get the full explanation from an Apple engineer.

You can [skip to the 33'36" mark](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/225/?time=2016) for the interesting bit.

[image: Collection View Updates Coalescing Slide]

#### Summary of the video

- 2 lists: "original items" (before any changes) and "final items" (after all changes);
- Original indexes → indexes in original items
- Final indexes → indexes in final items

#### Operations order in `PerformBatchUpdates`

1. Deletes → Always use original indexes (will be used in descending order)
2. Inserts → Always use final indexes (will be used in ascending order)
3. Moves   → From = original index; To = final index
4. Reload  → Under the hood, it deletes then inserts. Index = original index. You can't reload an item that is moved.

To reload an item that is moved, call all reloads in a separate `PerformBatchUpdates`, inside a `PerformWithoutAnimation` (as reloads are never animated).